# Changing Iframe src dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting value from localstorage and want to pass it to the url in iframe.
I am trying this code

```html
<script>
  // getting value from localstorage

  var x = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
  //alert showing the value 

  alert(x);
  //but this is not working.
  document.getElementById("framee").src = 'https://thingspeak.com/channels/' + x + '/charts/1?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=60&type=line&update=15';
</script>

<body>

  <iframe id="framee"></iframe>

</body>
```

alert is showing me the value but when the next line is executed no frame is shown in on web. the question is how to pass the value in url so it can be a proper syntax.

Comment: Could you do an `alert(document.getElementById("framee").src` please?

Comment: try to take your code in variable like as:
var iframeSrc = document.getElementById("framee").src = 'https://thingspeak.com/channels/' + x + '/charts/1?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=60&type=line&update=15';

Comment: Thanks for your precious time it is now solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code runs to early, JS tries to find a element with that id, but there isn't a element because the body isn't loaded. Try to place to code to the bottom of the page or put it in a function and execute that function on for example page load.

```
    <script>
    function loadIframe(){
    // getting value from localstorage

    var x = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
    //alert showing the value 

    alert(x);
    //but this is not working.
    document.getElementById("framee").src='https://thingspeak.com/channels/' + x +'/charts/1?bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%23d62020&dynamic=true&results=60&type=line&update=15';
    }
    </script>

    <body onLoad="loadIframe()"> 

    <iframe id="framee" ></iframe>

    </body>
```

Comment: yes it was not finding the ID. Now it is working :) thankyou